# ios AVAudioPlayer get wrong duration

Tags: ios, avaudioplayer

I use [NCMusicEngine](https://github.com/nickcheng/NCMusicEngine) to achieve playing mp3 while downloading But when I play some specific remote mp3 file I get the duration of mp3 is wrong, example I get the value is 58 it shoule be 29 It looks like double of the actual value , then I play the remote mp3 in chrome ,it works fine,

I try to use `AVAssetURL` to get the duration of remote mp3 file ,the same error is happen

**what happen?**

Answer (score 1):

In my project i use something like this:

```
AVURLAsset *asset = [[AVURLAsset alloc] initWithURL:url options:nil];
float t = CMTimeGetSeconds(asset.duration);
```

And it's return the right duration.

Comment: Can u post more code where you try this, with your url?

Comment: [mp3](http://7xkjiu.media1.z0.glb.clouddn.com/t3bIIoCxA_EkKFTxQjmRNjUbtx4=/FlPTZAyIRvmQ_3uFG9to-uMsJst9)  this is my play url @ADS

Comment: In my opinion it something wrong on server side, where mp3 stored. I try put link into my project, and it show duration 72 second. Later, i download file from your link, and open it in iTunes. iTunes show duration 1m, 12s (72 sec)

Comment: Also I tried to open a link in various browsers. 
Safari displays the correct duration (1m, 12s). Firefox displays (36 sec).

Comment: When I am playing a url on a browser it's returning me a right duration but when the same url I'm playing on AVAudioPlayer then its getting me a wrong duration. Is there any help? please guide me.